# Error during executing the mapreduce(map reduce) program on Windows10

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Good Moring All Please help me to over come below issue

Data Stored to the Hadoop(HDFS)

C:\Users\intex>hadoop fs -cat /input_dir/input_file.txt

```
23   23   27  43   24   25   26   26   26   26   25   26  25
26   27   28  28   28   30   31   31   31   30   30   30  29
31   32   32  32   33   34   35   36   36   34   34   34  34
39   38   39  39   39   41   42   43   40   39   38   38  40
38   39   39  39   39   41   41   41   28   40   39   39  45
23   23   27  43   24   25   26   26   26   26   25   26  25
26   27   28  28   28   30   31   31   31   30   30   30  29
31   32   32  32   33   34   35   36   36   34   34   34  34
39   38   39  39   39   41   42   43   40   39   38   38  40
```

We tried to run the MapReduce program on above data by command

```
hadoop jar E:/MapReduceClient.jar wordcount /input_dir /output_dir
```

Systems started prompting an error , i googled and implemented couple of suggestion they didn't worked

Output is as follows:

```
18/06/03 06:39:49 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
18/06/03 06:39:52 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/06/03 06:39:53 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/06/03 06:39:53 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1527987986422_0002
18/06/03 06:39:54 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1527987986422_0002
18/06/03 06:39:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ARS:8088/proxy/application_1527987986422_0002/
18/06/03 06:39:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1527987986422_0002
18/06/03 06:39:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1527987986422_0002 running in uber mode : false
18/06/03 06:39:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/06/03 06:39:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1527987986422_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1527987986422_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1527987986422_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://ARS:8088/cluster/app/application_1527987986422_0002 Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Failed to setup local dir /tmp/hadoop-intex/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
18/06/03 06:39:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Comment: `For more detailed output, check application tracking page`.... Your error exists there

Comment: The possible issue is regarding the yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent , because AM fails mainly if it's not getting the memory required to run the job or if any of your processes aren't working in right manner